# I have a new Silex application, and only index works

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, silex

This is my second Silex project, the first works fine. It is a one-page website with multi-language and twig support. Only multi-language doesn't work because nothing but the root route works. Not even `$app->error()`.

The domain is `dev.domainname.com/projectname/`

The Directory Structure is:

- /var/www

  - projectname

    - application

      - web

        - index.php/.htaccess, etc...

And this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectname/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The `rewrite module` is loaded according to `apachectl -M | grep "rewrite"`

**Edit** I forgot to mention that the application is stored in `/var/www/...` but the document root for `dev.domainname.com` is actually in a deeper parallel folder, and there is a symbolic link to the folder. Not sure how relevant this is.

Comment: project name is your root? but you have the .htaccess file 2 levels deep? Where exactly is the htaccess file?

Comment: .htaccess is in the folder with index.php in the web folder.`application` is the root. Ultimately there will be an `application2`, `application3`, etc..

Comment: Then try your rewritebase as `RewriteBase /web/`